# Where to store sessions in php5.5.14

Tags: php, session, php-5.5

I just installed php 5.5.14 from 5.4.20 and I am having problems getting the session to start. PHP says, `session.save_path` can't be found.

While using 5.4 I could go to `/var/lib/php` and would `chmod 777 sessions -R` and the problem would be fixed, but now I can't find a sessions folder in that directory.
I checked the `php.ini` and `session.save_path` points to `/tmp` folder. I would like to know where the session folder is found, if it is hidden somewhere in php5.5.14

#### Edit

I am using Nginx, on CentOS 6.5 I am using PHP from [webtatic](https://webtatic.com/) rpm

Comment: Did you check your httpd.conf if the session.save_path has the right path?

Comment: @Xatenev I am using Nginx

Comment: Maybe your file system is on read only? (I am not experienced with nginx anyways)

Comment: Anyways u shud definetly check your php.ini for your session save path! Maybe its the wrong path in there!

Comment: @Xatenev my php.ini says `session.save_path=/tmp`

Comment: try iterating through `ini_get('session.save_path')`, see what's returned.

Comment: @JackWilliam well, I tried `var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'))`  and I got this `string(20) "/var/lib/php/session"` I can't find a `session` folder in the stated directory though